# VPN connection enable and disable and using inside my android application

Tags: android, networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm new working in VPN, I want to make the following

1- install VPN Connection on my device.
2- open my application
3- when I press connect a dialog with vpn connection list will be open 
4- choose the vpn that I want to use
5- ability to disable and enable VPN connection

it seems to trivial assignment, I have searched for OpenVPN but I couldn't run it, also searched for ToyVPN but it is only working in API 14

can any one help me out with some resources that can guide me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToyVPN works on API 14+, not only on API 14. Specifically for OpenVPN the app OpenVPN for Android includes a remote API and a remote API example app.